# Problems getting fastpython protobuf support

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I see that there is supposed to be support for creating python wrappers to the C++ generated protobuf readers.

From http://yz.mit.edu/wp/fast-native-c-protocol-buffers-from-python/
 I find a simple way to turn on support by setting the environment variable:

PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=cpp

if I do that I get the following error:

```
    import pyFileLib.db_proc_geo_pb2
  File "C:\sandbox\PrortoBuf\lib\pyFileLib\db_proc_geo_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 46, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: cannot import name '_message'
```

I see a way to extend the protoc generator to natively generate fastpython ouput:
https://github.com/Cue/fast-python-pb

```
git clone https://github.com/Cue/fast-python-pb.git

cd fast-python-pb

python setup.py install
```

I get the following error when trying to run protoc with --fastpython_out:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugin_pb2'

--fastpython_out: protoc-gen-fastpython: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

It looks like this is related to:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/5Ywz8gwn9Kk

> python installation of protocol buffers does not generate the
>   google.protobuf.compiler.plugin_pb2 python file, while
>   google.protobuf.descriptor_pb2 is explicitly generated by
>   protobuf/python/setup.py

How do I go about making this explicit installation happen...or otherwise making protobuf performance in python acceptable?

Answer (score 6):

I found this little gem at the end of https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated

> There is also a C++ implementation for Python messages via a Python
>   extension for better performance. Implementation type is controlled by
>   an environment variable PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION (valid
>   values: "cpp" and "python"). The default value is currently "python"
>   but will be changed to "cpp" in future release.
>
> Note that the environment variable needs to be set before installing
>   the protobuf library, in order to build and install the python
>   extension. The C++ implementation also requires CPython platforms. See
>   python/INSTALL.txt for detailed install instructions.

WinPython 3.6.3 distributions came with protobuf already installed, but apparently this flag was not set during the installation

use the following commands to fix this:

```
set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=cpp

python -mpip install protobuf --upgrade
```

Comment: Just ran into this same thing years later when updating my WinPython to 3.8.9.0 I had to add -I on the pip command line to ignore the current installed version this time.